# Minimum Date supported by Box.com

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

Anyone knows the ***minimum date vale*** supported by api.box.com for search by *created_range* and *modified_range*

The URL for the same is: https://box-content.readme.io/#searching-for-content

Comment: I have used "01/01/0001" [C# DateTime.MinValue], It works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the API docs](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#api-docs-directory) under Date Format:

> Box supports the subset of dates after the start of the Unix epoch: 1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 (00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970).

Earlier dates may happen to work as well, but this is what's officially supported.